# A* PQ уходит в бесконечность

Tags: java, алгоритм

Алгоритм А* не работает должным образом, помогите понять что не так в данной реализации, цель задачи - решить проблему 8 королев. Список решения для будущего, пока ищу одно. Код:

```
List<int[]> AStar() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<int[]> solutions = new ArrayList<>();
    if (size < 4) solutions.add(board);
    else {
        PriorityQueue<State> states = new PriorityQueue<>();
        states.add(new State(board));
        while (!states.isEmpty()) {
            State current = states.poll();
            if (current.grade == 0) {
                solutions.add(current.getBoard());
                break;
            }
            states.add(current);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("A* on "  + size + " by " + size + " board has found solution in "
            + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start) + "ms...");
    return solutions;
}
```

Класс состояния доски в какой-то момент

```
public class State implements Comparable<State> {

int[] board;
int grade;

public State(int[] board) {
    this.board = board;
    grade = heuristic();
}

int heuristic() {
    int conflicts = 0;
    for (int queen = 0; queen < board.length; queen++) //            if (board[i] < 0) return 0;
        for (int enemy = 0; enemy < board.length && board[enemy] >= 0; enemy++)
            if (enemy != queen
                    && (board[queen] == board[enemy]
                    || queen + board[queen] == enemy + board[enemy]
                    || queen - board[queen] == enemy - board[enemy]))
                conflicts++;
    return conflicts >> 1;
}

public int[] getBoard() {
    return board;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(State o) {
    return Integer.compare(this.grade, o.grade);
}
```

}

Алгоритм лежит в классе

```
public class ChessBoard {
    int size;
    int[] board;

    ChessBoard(int size) throws IOException {
        board = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) putQueen(i, (int)(Math.random() * size));
    }
    void putQueen(int row, int col) {board[row] = col;}
```

Comment: А что значит должным образом? Приведите конкретный пример - как он должен работать и как работает сейчас. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: **1.** переработай вопрос: код есть, но не описал суть проблемы в каком месте зацикливание и тд.
**2.** приложенный код выглядит так как будто просто куски, связи между ними никакой нету (**что имею ввиду: непонятно кто кого вызывает и при каких обстоятельствах**)
**3.** думаю что проблема в цикле `while`, но нужно проходит отладчиком и смотреть, советую научиться пользоваться им :)

Comment: @DmitryK как должен - положить конкретное состояние в очередь с приоритетом, который вычисляется как кол-во конфликтующих пар королев без учета видимости, а дальше выбирает лучшее (первое в очереди) и если оно имеет 0 конфликтов - то работа завершена, иначе выбирает делает расчет новых состояний от текущего. Сейчас работает так, что состояния не меняется, ошибка в логике а стар, наверное, но я не знаю где именно...